# Choosing a distribution and packages for a print server

Tags: software-installation, samba, printing, cups

I'm helping out someone who's not very tech-savvy replace an older desktop computer, whose only current use is as an SMB print server, with a Raspberry Pi 2B.

I've never worked witha Pi before, but I'm sure I'll get by with the installation. What I was wondering is how to choose an appropriate distribution, and whether it's important for the print server to install additional packages beyond, CUPS, and Samba, to make life easier for the users and for me as a maintainer.

Please don't write answers saying distribution X is better than distribution Y, but rather regarding how potential issues or challenges are handled differently on different distributions.

I realize the answer might well be "It doesn't matter, they're all fine for your purpose" or "just imagine it's a weak regular PC and choose a distribution like you would there". If that's the case - just say so.

Comment: The wise thing to do is probably to use the *most popular* distribution, since most of the information you find online will implicitly refer to that context (if they don't explicitly refer to one).  That's Raspbian.  Beyond that, all the general purpose distros will be equivalent in terms of setting up a print server, and I doubt very much there is any distro around that "specializes as a print server".  Although you can install a "lite" version of Raspbian with no GUI, you probably should go for the GUI even if it is rarely used since they make life easier when you need to fiddle.

Comment: @goldilocks: It seems like your comment would make for a reasonable answer. Also, do you really believe I can narrow my question further? If so, how?

Comment: It just reads like you are fishing: *"whether I should install some particular piece of software beyond, you know, CUPS, and Samba..."* -> Ten people could give ten different answers there.  Which one of them is correct?  All of them?  Only a few of them?  Stuff like that is more suited to discussion forums.  It would make more sense for you to do more in-depth online research first (hint: Don't include "Raspberry Pi" in your search terms; setting up a print server is an OS related task, so search under the broader umbrella "linux"), then ask more specific questions if need be.

Comment: @goldilocks: Ok, how about now?

Comment: You will be better served at our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).